# PHP check mysql row for empty date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have created a new date column and it defaults it to `0000-00-00` and I want to check if it has a valid date or all zeros, but none of these codes seem to work for me and I can't figure out why. I know it sees the date, cause when I `echo` it, it displayed as zeros. How do I check to see if the date column is `0000-00-00`? Here is what I tried and none of them have worked.

```
if (trim($row['date']) == '' || substr($row['date'],0,10) == '0000-00-00') {
    // empty date
}

if (strtotime($row['date']) == '0000-00-00'){
   // empty date
}

if ($row['date'] == '0000-00-00'){
  // empty date
}
```

**EDIT**
Looks like it might just be a problem with my godaddy hosting server, I uploaded the files to a free webhosting and solution 3 is working over there. Sorry to waste everyone's time, I do appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: Why doesn't the 3rd if statement work?  That looks right to me.  You must have something else interfering.

Comment: @mickmackusa I am thinking it's a problem with my godaddy hosting server, I just uploaded everything to a free webhost and the 3rd option is working over there. Strange issue, guess I will have to call godaddy. UGH..

Comment: Then this should be closed as Off-topic Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `empty()` with `strtotime` will check all the empty cases

```
<?php
    $row['date'] = '0000-00-00';

    if(empty(strtotime($row['date']))){
        // empty date
    }
    else{
        //not empty date
    }
```

If about your 3 condition it should be like below instead of using `if` ladder use `else if` and In 2nd condition your are comparing timestamp integer(strtotime will return int seconds) to the string date('0000-00-00') that is in correct

```
<?php
    $row['date'] = '0000-00-00';
    if (trim($row['date']) == '' || substr($row['date'],0,10) == '0000-00-00') {
        // empty date
    }
    else if(strtotime($row['date']) == strtotime('0000-00-00')){
       // empty date
    }
    else if ($row['date'] == '0000-00-00'){
      // empty date
    }
```

Comment: Why use any functions at all?  The OP isnt telling us something.

Comment: OP said " I want to check if it has a valid date or all zeros"

Comment: Ok Fine lets do it

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following condition instead of yours...
There `strtotime()` return false if that not contains a specific date string or for proper check of empty string you can use `empty()` function and for check that string contains `'0000-00-00'` like data then you can use `strpos()` as like the below code:

```
if(empty(trim($row['date'])) || (strpos($row['date'], '0000-00-00') !== false) || (!strtotime($row['date'])))
{
    // empty date
}
```

Comment: Has everyone gone mad?

Answer (score 0):

If we aren't sure about how the date is being returned, try using date and strtotime together to ensure correct format:

```
if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date'])) > '0000-00-00'){
    //Valid
}
```

Comment: Why use any functions at all?  Is my microphone working?